# Which game does this screen capture depicting a wilderness scene belong to?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this game and wanted to know its name; seems like an MMO or MMORPG. I saw many people using headphones to talk to other people in this game when playing it.

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's [Dota 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/570/Dota_2/). The health and mana bars, the stats being shown inside the "o" of "problems", and the score bar at the top are all very distinctive.